# scala zip list to tuple

Tags: list, scala, zip, tuples, variable-assignment

Working with JodaTime, trying to convert a List[LocalDate] to Tuple2[JodaTime, JodaTime] so I can do multi-assigment like so:

```
val(expire, now) = 
  List(row.expireDate, new JodaDate) zip (_.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis)
```

which of course does not compile. Is there a similarly concise way to do the above? I know I can just do it manually:

```
val(expire, now) = 
  (row.expireDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis, 
   new JodaDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis)
```

but that's a bit ugly

Comment: Quite an exaggerated problem IMO. Why introduce all those redundant dynamic computation cycles spent on creation of a `List`, a function literal, iteration and pattern matching? I mean what's the actual purpose of all that? Obfuscating a simple code? Well then this is a good example of a bad coding style. The problem couldn't be more trivial: you just need to assign two variables, so assign them: `val expire = row.expireDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis; val now = new JodaDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis` - there's no need to build a house and demolish it before that.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, [\*cough\*](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5324)

Comment: @missingfaktor These are completely different things. Love your sarcasm though )

Comment: @NikitaVolkov safe to say that the accepted answer will not drag my application to a grinding crawl, despite the overwhelming load placed on the server, *cough* ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val Seq(expire, now) = 
  Seq(row.expireDate, new JodaDate).map(_.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis)
```

Comment: It's all pattern matching and extractors. You can also do `val expire :: now :: Nil = List(row.expireDate, new JodaDate).map(_.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis)`.

Comment: I knew about val a :: b assignment but have been using val(a,b) for the nicer syntax. At any rate, clearly many ways to achieve the same thing in Scala

Answer (score 4):

What you want (assuming you don't want to go the conversion-to-`Seq` route) is [Scalaz's `Bifunctor` instance](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/Bifunctor.scala.html) for tuples (which isn't in the standard library). With it you can write the following:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val cap = (_: String).toUpperCase
cap: String => java.lang.String = <function1>

scala> val removeLs = (_: String).replaceAll("l", "")
removeLs: String => java.lang.String = <function1>

scala> cap <-: ("hello", "world") :-> removeLs
res0: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (HELLO,word)
```

Or, in your case:

```
val f = (_: JodaDate).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.getMillis
val (expire, now) = f <-: (row.expireDate, new JodaDate) :-> f
```

Comment: ahhhhhh, hieroglyphic syntax soup, no thanks. Not yet ready for Scalaz, still learning Scala itself -- I'll dive in for sure, but not right now ;-)

Comment: It's actually not that complicated, and "mapping" over tuples can be very handy—this is one of the few bits of Scalaz that I actually use.

Comment: @virtualeyes, `f <-: (a, b) :-> g = (f(a), g(b))`.

Comment: Scalaz gateway drug seems to be Validation, which will likely be my entry point. I have +1'd here as, yes, looking at your example again, I see how this approach could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
val Seq(a, b) =
  Seq("a", "b").map(_.toUpperCase)

println("a, b = %s, %s".format(a, b)) // a, b = A, B
```

Comment: Darn, missingfaktor beat me by a minute.

Comment: I plus 1'd you anyway, no worries ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the type safety of using a tuple (remember, when unapplying a `Seq`, the compiler will not check the length), you can write a wrapper to add a function not available in the standard library, which will let you map over a tuple.

In the case of mapping over both elements using a single function, because a `Tuple2[A, B]` has two type parameters, the key to making this work is to require evidence that `A` and `B` are the same type. To do this, require an implicit parameter of type `B =:= A`; if the types are indeed equal, the compiler will supply a function of type `B => A`.

```
class Tuple2Wrapper[A, B](t: (A, B)) {
  def bimap[C, D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (C, D) = (f(t._1), g(t._2))
  def <-:->[C](f: A => C)(implicit ev: B =:= A): (C, C) = bimap(f, f compose ev)
}

implicit def tuple2Tuple2Wrapper[A, B](t: (A, B)) = new Tuple2Wrapper(t)

scala> (1, 1) <-:-> (_ + 1)
res1: (Int, Int) = (2,2)
```

This could be done in a more general and useful way (applicable to more types than just `Tuple2`), if implemented in terms of Scalaz's `Bifunctor` trait.

Comment: Is there any reason why the wrapper shouldn't just take an (A,A) tuple? Why add another parameter and then check if it's the same?

Comment: @Kaito you are right, the wrapper could be written just for `(A, A)`. I originally wrote it as a specialised method on a wrapper with other, `[A, B]`-parameterised methods, and did not think to simplify the example after taking these other methods away.