# Extract values from Array into Tuple

Tags: scala, collections

Is there a simple way to extract the values of a list into a tuple in Scala?

Basically something like

```
"15,8".split(",").map(_.toInt).mkTuple //(15, 8)
```

Or some other way I can do

```
val (x, y) = "15,8".split(",").map(_.toInt)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you have them in an array you can write `Array` in front of the variable names like so:

```
val Array(x, y) = "15,8".split(",").map(_.toInt)
```

Just replace with `Seq` or similar if you have another collection-type.

It basically works just like an [extractor](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) behind the scenes. Also see this related thread: [scala zip list to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363584/scala-zip-list-to-tuple)

Comment: Is there a way to create `tuple` result directly without creating two vals `x` and `y`? (I really like inline solutions)

Answer (score 6):

You could try pattern matching:

```
val (x, y) = "15,8".split(",") match {
  case Array(x: String, y: String) => (x.toInt, y.toInt)
  case _ => (0, 0) // default
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping for something a bit less verbose, it's simpler to do it the way I'm currently doing it which is 
var s = l.split(",").map(_.toInt)
val (x, n) = (s(0), s(1))
I was just hoping to get rid of the intermediate step with 's'

Comment: With pattern matching you can easiely return a fallback value if you don't get two strings from split and it's not introducing unnecessary vals.

Comment: Just for the record: the `case _ => (0, 0)` part is really suggesting something the original asker did not ask about at all.